# how to combine 2 methods with different objects (same code in both methods)

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico

New poster here, but have been using SO for a long time now.

I'm a bit rusty from C# coding and I have something I'd like to optimize in my code. I have 2 methods that have the exact same code, but with a different object (the object has some different properties, but the ones that are used are the same in both methods). The query is built differently before the call to the method. Is there a way to combine the methods easily so that I can still use it with one or the other object?

```
private static void SetQueryMainFilters(DocumentQueryObject documentQuery, DocumentQuery repeaterQuery, out DocumentQuery outRepeaterQuery)
{
    if (documentQuery.NodeID > 0)
    {
        repeaterQuery.WhereEquals(KenticoConstants.NODE_ID, documentQuery.NodeID);
    }

    if (documentQuery.DocumentID > 0)
    {
        repeaterQuery.WhereEquals(KenticoConstants.DOCUMENT_ID, documentQuery.DocumentID);
    }

    outRepeaterQuery = repeaterQuery;
}

private static void SetQueryMainFilters(DocumentQueryObject documentQuery, MultiDocumentQuery repeaterQuery, out MultiDocumentQuery outRepeaterQuery)
{
    if (documentQuery.NodeID > 0)
    {
        repeaterQuery.WhereEquals(KenticoConstants.NODE_ID, documentQuery.NodeID);
    }

    if (documentQuery.DocumentID > 0)
    {
        repeaterQuery.WhereEquals(KenticoConstants.DOCUMENT_ID, documentQuery.DocumentID);
    }

    outRepeaterQuery = repeaterQuery;
}
```

One of the method that calls the duplicated method

```
public static MultiDocumentQuery RepeaterMultiDocumentQuery(DocumentQueryObject documentQuery)
{
    MultiDocumentQuery repeaterQuery = new MultiDocumentQuery();
    [...]
    SetQueryMainFilters(documentQuery, repeaterQuery, out repeaterQuery);

    return repeaterQuery;
}
```

Currently, I have a MultiDocumentQuery object and a DocumentQueryObject. The code is the same in both methods, but the object is different.

Is there a proper way to do this so I can avoid code duplication? If you have a better solution to offer me, I have my ears open for suggestions. I need to be able to either call the Multi query builder or the regular query builder, with pretty much the same properties but different behavior. It uses Kentico's DocumentQuery and MultiDocumentQuery.

Thanks!

Comment: did you try inheritance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a base class from which `DocumentQuery` and `MultiDocumentQuery` will inherit, and the said base class should contain the `WhereEquals()` method.

```
public class DocumentBase
{
    public void WhereEquals() { }
}

public class DocumentQuery : DocumentBase
{
    // Other stuff
}

public class MultiDocumentQuery : DocumentBase
{
    // Other stuff
}

public class DocumentQueryObject
{
    public int NodeID { get; set; }
    public int DocumentID { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you can unify the two methods like so:

```
private static void SetQueryMainFilters(
    DocumentQueryObject documentQuery, 
    DocumentBase repeaterQuery, 
    out DocumentBase outRepeaterQuery)
{
    if (documentQuery.NodeID > 0)
    {
        repeaterQuery.WhereEquals();
    }

    if (documentQuery.DocumentID > 0)
    {
        repeaterQuery.WhereEquals();
    }

    outRepeaterQuery = repeaterQuery;
}
```

And this would mean, when calling it you'd have to create an object of the base class, but `new` is using the appropriate type.

```
DocumentBase single = new DocumentQuery();
SetQueryMainFilters(documentQuery, single, out single);
DocumentBase multi = new MultiDocumentQuery();
SetQueryMainFilters(documentQuery, multi, out multi);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of concept I am still not familiar with, but it's exactly what I needed. Haven't coded C# for a long time. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
private static void SetQueryMainFilters<TQuery>(DocumentQueryObject documentQuery, TQuery repeaterQuery, out TQuery outRepeaterQuery) where TQuery : DataQueryBase<TQuery>, new()
{ 
    if (documentQuery.NodeID > 0)
    {
        repeaterQuery.WhereEquals(KenticoConstants.NODE_ID, documentQuery.NodeID);
    }

    if (documentQuery.DocumentID > 0)
    {
        repeaterQuery.WhereEquals(KenticoConstants.DOCUMENT_ID, documentQuery.DocumentID);
    }

    outRepeaterQuery = repeaterQuery;
}
```

Comment: I was exactly looking into the Kentico Base class when I saw your comment. This is exactly what I needed (for Kentico). This is the proper answer I needed but I can't accept both answers. I'll leave the accepted answer to the previous answer as there's a lot more details to it than the specific Kentico answer you provided. But seriously, thanks for the time saver.